# How do I clean up my git branches to have a clean history going forward?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I am working on a project with the following branches:

- alpha
- beta
- prod

All changes are committed to **alpha** through PRs and then merged to **beta** and then **prod** before release.

The issue I am facing is that the merges from **alpha** to **beta** and **beta** to **prod** have been done through the same PR process which is creating a very messy history.

So when we are merging **alpha** to **beta**, for example, we create a feature branch based on **beta**, merge **alpha** onto that branch and then submit a PR to merge the feature branch into **beta**.

Instead, I want to have direct commits with fast-forward when possible when merging from one branch to the other. This would help with keeping a cleaner history and finding commits in the different branches.

What would be the best way to "re-align" my branches before I start with this new process.

I was thinking I will need to do a full merge from **prod** to **beta** and then **beta** to **alpha** which I think will allow me to have clean merges and history from **alpha** to **beta** and then **beta** to **prod** going forward. Will that be the case?

P.S.: I do NOT want to do force push to rewrite history on the existing branches. I am hoping this can be "fixed".

This is what our history looks like if we are only looking at **alpha**, **beta** and **prod**:

[image]

Comment: "So when we are merging alpha to beta, for example, we create a feature branch based on beta" Yeah, well that sounds wrong. To merge alpha to beta you should just merge it. If you simply followed the basic rule that says features come from alpha and merge to alpha, alpha merges only to beta, beta merges only to prod, your history would be clean; that's what we do. Part of the problem seems to be that someone is violating the rules you just enunciated; that blue track coming off of beta and merging back to beta is just wrong. Rules are pointless if people don't obey them.

Comment: I fail to see how this comment is helpful in any way. I have already acknowledged that we have been doing it wrong and the question is about trying to correct it. I do not need a lecture about following rules

Comment: Well sorry, it's unclear what else you want. In a comment you say you are ok with the past history being dirty, and if you just follow the rules you already enunciated going forward the future history will be clean, as I said in my previous comment, so it isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: I just explained what I was thinking about doing and I was asking whether or not this would work to have a clean history going forward. It was also implied but I should have made it clear that I was hoping for suggestions if the approach I am thinking about is not the best. You just confirmed that my approach should work so that answers my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a fetch and rebase approach, where e.g. instead of merging beta into alpha you fetch the latest revision from beta and rebase your alpha commits on  top. In the history all alpha commits will follow after the beta commits. Merging alpha back to beta would be fast forward. Then delete alpha and branch a new alpha from beta to proceed with  alpha development  ...

Comment: I would have to do a force push to beta with this approach, wouldn't I?
I would like to avoid having to do a force push.
I am also ok with the past history being dirty as long as I can recover and have clean history going forward

Comment: There's no force push needed. But you will have to resolve any conflicts that occur during rebase ...

Answer (score 0):

With three Git branches you could issue four rebase commands to bring them all in sync.

```
git rebase prod alpha
git rebase alpha beta
git rebase beta prod
git rebase prod alpha
```

Before doing so squash all the commits on each branch into one if you really want to clean things up and the commit history isn't important.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~<# of commits on the branch>
```

You'd get the same result as in the following branch diagram, with all of the files from the tips of each of the three repositories all together on A'

[image: Quadruple rebase to bring all branches into sync]

If you really wanted to get courageous, you could further squash the commits and make it look like the branch operations never even happened in the first place.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~<# of commits to squash>
```

In a similar [Git clean up](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/How-to-clean-up-Git-branches-and-commits) situation with three branches I brought the whole repo down to two commits.

[image]